# How do I use the append (+=) operator for JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to use the append (`+=`) operator for a JSX expression:

```
let j = "";
for (let i in [1,2,3]) {
  j += <span>{i}</span>;
}
```

But it unexpectedly renders as three strings, instead of HTML:

`[object Object][object Object][object Object]`

Answer (score 2):

The append operator is not supported in JSX.  Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```
[1,2,3].map((i) =>
  <span>{i}</span>
);
```

Comment: Or `push` since it's an array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print html into the JSX coming from any method or coming dynamically then you could do -

```js
let j = "";
for (let i in [1,2,3]) {
  j += `<span>${i}</span>`;
}
```

And in JSX,

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: j}} />
```

This will render 123 into your UI.

Note - Please research more about dangerouslySetInnerHTML before using it.